# Auto refresh in Mac not working for some site

Tags: html, ios, macos, page-refresh, frameset

I got a code that refreshes the html page as per the seconds I desire. I am on an Mac and I use the TextEdit app to make the HTML file. This code works for www.apple.com but it does not work for say, https://www.bitcointalk.org or http://www.macrumors.com.

I am not sure why this is happening. All I am doing is replacing the apple URL with bitcointalk url. I know I can also do this refreshing via Safari extension, but I need this code to work.

Thanks a lot

The code I am using is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
<FRAMESET>
<FRAME src="http://www.apple.com/">;
</FRAMESET>
</html>
```

EDIT: What I am trying to do is, create this html and move it to my iPhone, so that I can do the web refresh through my phone. Right now there are only paid apps in the App store that lets you refresh a page automatically every few seconds/minute and they are not really that good.

Comment: Probably because those websites in question don't allow access via frames. Haven't done my homework on that though, so I'll let someone who has post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @esqew pointed out in their comment, the sites that aren't showing up forbid access via frames by setting the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header to `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options